# "had been" vs. "was"

Tags: grammar

> Two women rescued a child who was kidnapped by his neighbour.

or

> Two women rescued a child who had been kidnapped by his neighbour.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: Please take a look at this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93733/simple-past-vs-past-perfect) which is related. I think it has the answer. If you don't find it satisfactory, please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Two women rescued a child who had been kidnapped by his neighbour

The action in the independent clause is set in the past and it's over (*rescued*, past simple). The kidnap happened before the rescue, so you use a past perfect (*had been kidnapped*).