# "had spent" vs. "spent"

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect

Which tense would be appropriate in this case - past perfect simple or past simple?

"After *he had spent* some of the money, he decided to find his dream house."

or

"After *he spent* some of the money, he decided to find his dream house."

Comment: There are many question on this site about the differences between the simple past and the past perfect tenses. For example: [Simple past vs. past perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93733/simple-past-vs-past-perfect).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple past vs. past perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93733/simple-past-vs-past-perfect)

Answer (score 2):

If the order of the two actions in the past is important, you should use the past perfect tense to show that "spending some of the money" was completed before "deciding to look for the dream house".